# How to pass pathname from _document to _app in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and i'm having a hard time with passing the data from _document to the _app.

I need to pass pathname server-side from `_document.ts` to `_app.ts` and then into `App` component so that i can inject custom  tags in `Head` element server-side. Every page will have specific links.

eg `<link rel="x-default" hrefLang="x-default" href="https://example.com/about-us">`

will be on page `https://example.com/about-us`.

Current implementation looks like this:

getInitialProps in _document.tx

```
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
      });
    const { lang } = ctx.query;
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      pathname: ctx.asPath,
      locale: getLocaleFromLanguage(lang as SupportedLanguages),
      styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
    };
```

part of _app.ts

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(pageProps)
  let { locale } = pageProps;
  if (!locale) {
    locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
    smoothscroll.polyfill();
  }, []);
```

when i `console.log(pageProps)` i only get eg `{ locale: 'en' }`, there is no `pathname` property passed from _document.ts.

Do you have idea how can i pass props from _document to _app

Comment: I have same issue like this. Did you solve it?

Comment: @elyas.m nope, had to find totally different approach..

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue and I used the req object to send my params from the _app to the _document. Based on NextJs resolution order we can use the req (IncomingMessage) object.
NextJs resolution order on the server-side :

1. app.getInitialProps
2. page.getInitialProps
3. document.getInitialProps
4. app.render
5. page.render
6. document.render

and on the client-side:

1. app.getInitialProps
2. page.getInitialProps
3. app.render
4. page.render

Example (TS): I Sent a property named direction from the _app's getInitialProps function to _document.

```
(ctx.req as any).direction = organization.direction;
```

And in _document's getInitialProps :

```
const direction = ctx.req.direction;
```